# On Bible Translations That Catholics are Permitted to Read

Tags: catholicism, bible, papacy, imprimatur

I have started to read "Introduction to the Bible" by Fr. John Laux, M.A.. The following is extracted from pg. 20:

> The Third Plenary Council of Baltimore (1884) says in its Pastoral Letter: "It can hardly be necessary to remind you, beloved brethren, that the most highly valued treasury of every family library, and the most frequently and lovingly made use of , should be the Holy Scriptures."

> 3. We are not, however, allowed to read any and every translation of the Bible , but only such as has been approved by ecclesiastical authority....

Undoubtedly, among other things perhaps, the said "approval by ecclesiastical authority" requires a valid *Imprimatur*.

Does anyone know which Pope decreed such and which encyclical (or some other document) may the described prohibition be contained in?

Comment: I don’t have the time now to do some research, but I would start here, and maybe you can find what you are looking for starting here as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_Librorum_Prohibitorum

Answer (score 2):

The following c.f. the [*Catechism of Pius X*](https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/library/catechism-of-st-pius-x-1286) (1908):

> 33 Q. Why does the Church forbid Protestant Bibles?
>
> A. The Church forbids Protestant Bibles because, either they have been altered and contain errors, or not having her approbation and footnotes explaining the obscure meanings, they may be harmful to the Faith. It is for that same reason that the Church even forbids translations of the Holy Scriptures already approved by her which have been reprinted without the footnotes approved by her.

Also, [Canon 825 of the *1983 Code of Canon Law*](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib3-cann822-833_en.html#:%7E:text=is%20otherwise%20evident.-,Can.,with%20necessary%20and%20sufficient%20annotations) says:

> Can. 825 §1. Books of the sacred scriptures cannot be published unless the Apostolic See or the conference of bishops has approved them. For the publication of their translations into the vernacular, it is also required that they be approved by the same authority and provided with necessary and sufficient annotations.